# Including articles as appendix in dissertation

Tags: standalone, import, appendix

For my dissertation, I need to include my published articles as an appendix. My articles are standalone LaTeX projects with their own preamble, template to adhere to the style guide for the publisher, and bibliography.

I have tried with the `standalone` and `import` packages, but I can't get it right. I was hoping that someone had been in a similar situation and found a good solution to this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best strategy for this purpose is to not include the LaTeX code, but the PDF. This can be easily done by using the package `pdfpages`.
The basic use fills the whole page  but  if needed, options enable to reduce the used area, and/or add header/footer.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that I also tried this. I think the issue I was having here, is that some of my PDFs are very large. Or at least I think this was the issue. The result, however, was that OverLeaf failed to generate the PDF and would not compile.

Comment: When you say "very large", do you mean the page number or the overall file size ? On the former case, have you tried to include only a few pages? On the latter, if you have the opportunity to use the publisher's pdf, it is likely  smaller than yours.

Comment: So it seems to sort of work. I cannot include the entire thing, like `\includepdf[pages=-]{publications/....pdf} `, but I can do `\includepdf[pages=2]{publications/...pdf}`. If I try to include more, OverLeaf throws an error "failed to render the PDF".

Comment: This seems to be a kind of overleaf problem. If you could share one of the offending PDF files, one would have the opportunity to   try on a regular tex distribution...

Comment: Few years ago I have experienced some problems related to the documemt size, and they where fixed by simply  switching to xelatex. It could be an opportunity, at least for a try with a dummy document.